# "The target server failed to respond" with default Jmeter's implementation of HTTPSample

Tags: jmeter, httpclient

I have following situation:
there is some Jmeter test. I run it from different locations. I get below error for some requests.

> org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException', 'Non HTTP response message:
>   The target server failed to respond'

Error is not permanent, it happens from time to time.
The weird thing here is that for some location this error happened and for some not.

Jmeter configuration (jmeter.properties) is identical for all locations, however mentioned error occurred only for some of them.

I've searched regarding that error and find a post about problem with HttpClient4 (which is default for HttpSampler implementation).
When I change implementation to 'Java' - problem gone.

However I can't understand why does the test works from one location and failed from another. Does somebody have any ideas regarding that? The only idea I have is some kind of firewall that has some connections limitation from some specific address.

p.s. All URL that fails where accessible from all locations with the browser, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Read this:

- https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed

It explains why issue happens with HTTP Client.

Browsers by default do stale check and retries which may explain why you don't reproduce in Browsers.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I was getting the same problem when trying to get a token from WSO2

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:61)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:481)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:298)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Changing the Protocol to https worked for me.